# Bounded operator with finite continuous spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a complex Hilbert space $H$. Let $\sigma_c(T)$ denote its continuous spectrum. It seems that $\sigma_c$ can in general be [quite weird](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849562/proof-that-the-continuous-part-of-a-spectrum-really-is-interval-like?rq=1) and not "continuous" in appearance at all. I would like to know if there is a way to systematically construct operators whose continuous spectrum is, say, a given finite set of isolated points.

More concretely:

**Question:** Is there an example of $T$ for which $\sigma_c(T)$ consists of two points?

*Thoughts:* When $T$ is normal, an isolated point in its spectrum must be an eigenvalue, so one must look at the situation when $T$ is not normal. The [Volterra operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63362/continuous-spectrum-can-shrink-to-an-isolated-point) has $\sigma_c(T)=\{0\}$. I wonder if one can use this to construct an operator with $\sigma_c(T)$ being two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the direct sum of two copies of $H$.  Let your operator be the Volterra operator $T$ on the first copy and $I+T$ on the second.
That is, if we write $H = H_1 \oplus H_2$ with $H_1$ and $H_2$ the two copies, take $(f,g) \mapsto (Tf, (I+T)g)$.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I had thought of doing this but made a mistake in my reasoning.